# Merge two datatables into a single one in C#

Tags: c#

I have two datatables, first has one column `No Of Specification` and the second has column `NoOfSpec`, but I want to merge under single column as `No Of Specification`.

Data table #1

```
No Of Specification       
--------------------      
1                            
2                            
3
```

Data table #2

```
NoOfSpec
---------------------
4
5
6
```

and the result should be

```
No Of Specification
----------------------
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Note: there are multiple columns in both the tables

Comment: means the first table contains rows and second contains column and then result table will be column, right?

Comment: No both table contain column it is just typo mistake

Comment: What is expected for common values in both tables? if 2 exists in both table does 2 repeats twice in the resulting table?

Comment: it need to be get once should not be repeat

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach you could take to join the data using Linq. The `Union` of the data rows in the two tables are taken, and an anonymous object is created for each in which you set the key for the merge - in your case, `No of Specification` for the first table and `NoOfSpec` from the second. Then, we use a `GroupBy` on that union to get unique values for the merge. Finally, we select the first occurrence of each unique key from the union and copy to a new `DataTable`.

```
DataTable firstTable = new DataTable();
firstTable.Columns.Add("No of Specification", typeof(int));
firstTable.Columns.Add("OtherCol", typeof(string));
firstTable.Rows.Add(1, "A");
firstTable.Rows.Add(2, "B");
firstTable.Rows.Add(3, "C");

DataTable secondTable = new DataTable();
secondTable.Columns.Add("NoOfSpec", typeof(int));
secondTable.Columns.Add("OtherCol", typeof(string));
secondTable.Rows.Add(3, "F");
secondTable.Rows.Add(4, "G");
secondTable.Rows.Add(5, "H");

var mergedTable = firstTable.AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new { Key = dataRow["No of Specification"], Row = dataRow })
    .Union(secondTable.AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new { Key = dataRow["NoOfSpec"], Row = dataRow }))
    .GroupBy(a => a.Key, a => a.Row)
    .Select(a => a.First())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Output:

```
+----------+----------+
| NoOfSpec | OtherCol |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | A        |
| 2        | B        |
| 3        | C        |
| 4        | G        |
| 5        | H        |
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is following. I am assuming other columns are same. The other column I gave is named [value] which exists in both tables. For more columns you have to add them one by one as two columns of different names are being merged.

```
SELECT L.[No Of Specification] as [No Of Specification], L.[value]
FROM [Data Table 1] L
UNION --if you know there can not be duplicates
SELECT R.[NoOfSpec], R.[value]
FROM [Data Table 2] R
ORDER BY [No Of Specification]
```

Comment: I think the question refers to a C# DataTable rather than a SQL table.